# Jquery Tabs Add/Toggle classes based on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, tabs

I have some tabs set up with jQuery, but I would like to add the capability to change tabs based on URL. Ideally, once the URL is followed by the id/data-attribute, the browser scrolls to the appropriate section and the tab gets open.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

$('.gdlr-session-item-head-info').click(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('gdlr-active') ) return;
    $(".gdlr-session-item-head-info").removeClass('gdlr-active');


    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".gdlr-tab-session-item").offset().top-200
    }, 1000);

    var selected_tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var current_day = $(this).attr('current-day');
    $(".currentDay-"+current_day).addClass('gdlr-active');

    $('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings('.gdlr-session-item-tab-content').hide();
    $('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings('.' + selected_tab).fadeIn();
});
```

}

HMTL

```
<div class="session-item-wrapper" id="agendaroduct" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div class="gdlr-session-item gdlr-tab-session-item gdlr-item">
   <div class="gdlr-session-item-head">
      <a href="agenda/#currentDay-1">
         <div id="currentDay-1" class="gdlr-session-item-head-info  currentDay-0 gdlr-active" current-day="0" data-tab="gdlr-tab-1">
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Pre-Day</div>
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Tue, Nov 5</div>
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="agenda/#currentDay-2">
         <div id="currentDay-2" class="gdlr-session-item-head-info currentDay-1" current-day="1" data-tab="gdlr-tab-2">
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 1</div>
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Wed, Nov 6</div>
         </div>
      </a>
      <a href="agenda/#currentDay-3">
         <div id="currentDay-3" class="gdlr-session-item-head-info  currentDay-2" current-day="2" data-tab="gdlr-tab-3">
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 2</div>
            <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Thu, Nov 7</div>
         </div>
      </a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="gdlr-session-item-tab-content gdlr-tab-1 " style="display: block;">                                                          content goes here
   </div>
   <div class="gdlr-session-item-tab-content gdlr-tab-2 gdlr-active" style="display: none;">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    content goes here                   
   </div>
   <div class="gdlr-session-item-tab-content gdlr-tab-3 " style="display: none;">                   conten goes here
   </div>
   <div class="gdlr-session-item-head end">
      <div class="gdlr-session-item-head-info  currentDay-0 gdlr-active" current-day="0" data-tab="gdlr-tab-1">
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Pre-Day</div>
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Tue, Nov 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gdlr-session-item-head-info currentDay-1" current-day="1" data-tab="gdlr-tab-2">
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 1</div>
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Wed, Nov 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="gdlr-session-item-head-info  currentDay-2" current-day="2" data-tab="gdlr-tab-3">
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 2</div>
         <div class="gdlr-session-head-date">Thu, Nov 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide examples of what these URL's may look like? Could you demonstrate your attempts in getting this to work with the URL's you've implemented? Are you using pushState or attempting hash value lookup? etc.

Comment: @Cue Sure! Once any tab is clicked, it adds #currentDay-3 to the current url. But if I try to access one tab from typing the entire URL (Like: mydomain.com/#currentDay-3) it does not work.

Comment: Ok, that helps. Could you share some HTML so we can provide better suited solutions?

Comment: Also, am I correct in assuming you're hash is changing because there is also a link, e.g. `<a href="#currentDay-3">` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, just added the hmtl

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to find a method of connecting the hash value to a DOM element. In your case, your `id` attribute on your tab triggers match this and also contain the relevant information to show the correct tabs amongst other functionality (as you've demonstrated in your click event).

You could separate your tab change logic into a function which can then be called by both click events and on page load by passing the intended tab to show as a parameter.

```
function showTab(element) {
  if (element.hasClass("gdlr-active")) return;

  $(".gdlr-session-item-head-info").removeClass("gdlr-active");

  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".gdlr-tab-session-item").offset().top - 200
  }, 1000);

  var selected_tab = element.attr("data-tab");
  var current_day = element.attr("current-day");
  $(".currentDay-" + current_day).addClass("gdlr-active");

  $('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings(".gdlr-session-item-tab-content").hide();
  $('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings("." + selected_tab).fadeIn();
}
```

Your click handler would then be bound to call the function...

```
$('.gdlr-session-item-head-info').click(function(){
  showTab($(this));
})
```

When the page loads, you could verify the hash in the URL is an available DOM element and send that to your function also.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var targetTab = $(window.location.hash)
    if (targetTab.length) {
      showTab(targetTab);
    }
  }
})
```